# SQL Server Standard Basic Availability Group - only 10 Listeners limit?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, listener, sql-server-2017, standard-edition

Is there a limit to the number of listeners that can be created using SQL Server Standard?

I'm working with a DBA who has set up a 2017 Standard server, with CU3. We have 12 databases, and he was able to set up 12 basic availability groups. He was able to set up 10 listeners, but on the 11th, is getting the error below:

> Create failed for Availability Group Listener 'test12300'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=14.0.17213.0+((SSMS_Rel).171128-2020)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+AvailabilityGroupListener&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> The WSFC cluster could not bring the Network Name resource with DNS name 'test12300' online. The DNS name may have been taken or have a conflict with existing name services, or the WSFC cluster service may not be running or may be inaccessible. Use a different DNS name to resolve name conflicts, or check the WSFC cluster log for more information.
>   The attempt to create the network name and IP address for the listener failed. If this is a WSFC availability group, the WSFC service may not be running or may be inaccessible in its current state, or the values provided for the network name and IP address may be incorrect. Check the state of the WSFC cluster and validate the network name and IP address with the network administrator. Otherwise, contact your primary support provider. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 19471)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=14.00.3015&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=19471&LinkId=20476

We created 11 empty databases, backed up each, and then through the AG Wizard created an AG and a Listener using DHCP. It worked 10 times, but on the 11th it failed. For the 11th listener, we chose name BAG_L11, there is nothing else that uses that DNS name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the links below that describe the need to increase the ms-DS-MachineAccountQuota attribute from its default of 10. I think the original error message from the AG Wizard is a red herring.

Creating listeners with SQL Server AlwaysOn suddenly stopped working! - SOLVED
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717629/creating-listeners-with-sql-server-alwayson-suddenly-stopped-working-solved

Resolving an Error When Creating an Availability Group Listener
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/always+on/145147/

Looking at Failover Cluster Manager on wal1qa-dw1a supports the scenario described on those links too:
"The text for the associated error code is: Your computer could not be joined to the domain. You have exceeded the maximum number of computer accounts you are allowed to create in this domain. Contact your system administrator to have this limit reset or increased."

Update - Confirmed, made change to ms-DS-MachineAccountQuota attribute as detailed in above links, worked.

Answer (score 5):

The [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups) is only number of replicas.

> Limit of two replicas (primary and secondary).
>
> he was able to set up 12 basic availability groups. He was able to set up 10 listeners

You can create many AGs and listeners. The error you are getting is self explanatory

> **The DNS name may have been taken or have a conflict with existing name services**, or the WSFC cluster service may not be running or may be inaccessible. **Use a different DNS name to resolve name conflicts**, or check the WSFC cluster log for more information.

Also refer to [Top 7 Questions about Basic Availability Groups](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msftpietervanhove/2017/03/14/top-5-questions-about-basic-availability-groups/) and [Troubleshooting AlwaysOn availability group listener creation in SQL Server 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2829783/troubleshooting-alwayson-availability-group-listener-creation-in-sql-s).

Comment: The domain policy example is exactly what I think is going on now (and what I posted as an answer)